# Fabric js, Rotating point in each side

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I would like to configure fabricJS to add extra rotation controls. I know there is a control API, I am not sure how to use it. [control-api](http://fabricjs.com/controls-api)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'red', transparentCorners: false, top: 50, left: 50 });
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" ></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new control api allows you to add controls to the

```js
fabric.Object.prototype.controls
```

This object has a key for each control, and the one that actually hold the rotation is the `controls.mtr` by default.

we can add mtr1, mtr2 and mtr3 contols in this way.

```
const originalControl = fabric.Object.prototype.controls.mtr;
fabric.Object.prototype.controls.mtr1 = new fabric.Control({
 x: -0.5,
 y: 0,
 offsetX: -40,
 actionHandler: originalControl.actionHandler,
});
```

Look in the snippet for more details

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'red', transparentCorners: false, top: 50, left: 50 });
canvas.add(rect);

const originalControl = fabric.Object.prototype.controls.mtr;
fabric.Object.prototype.controls.mtr1 = new fabric.Control({
 x: -0.5,
 y: 0,
 offsetX: -40,
 actionHandler: originalControl.actionHandler,
 withConnection: true,
 actionName: 'rotate',
});
fabric.Object.prototype.controls.mtr2 = new fabric.Control({
 x: 0.5,
 y: 0,
 offsetX: 40,
 actionHandler: originalControl.actionHandler,
 withConnection: true,
 actionName: 'rotate',
});
fabric.Object.prototype.controls.mtr3 = new fabric.Control({
 x: 0,
 y: 0.5,
 offsetY: 40,
 actionHandler: originalControl.actionHandler,
 withConnection: true,
 actionName: 'rotate',
});

canvas.setActiveObject(rect);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400" ></canvas>
```

Ugly but work.
A note, not specifying `actionName: 'rotate'` does not keep the rotation point in the center. This is obviously wrong and should be addressed in the library probably.

Comment: It is working, but how can I disable the top one? also I want to do this only for some objects on my canvas not for all?

Comment: Update, It worked. by adding required `MTR` to my objects.